# How to verify the title in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to verify title in home page, I have tried below these two methods but I got error.

1.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);       
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("This is demo site for"));
```

ERROR:

```
Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for title to contain "This is demo site for". Current title: "Home page"
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
```

2.

```
String actualTitle=driver.getTitle();
String expectedTitle="This is demo site for";
assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
```

ERROR:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Home page]> but was:<[This is demo site for]>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page-title">
  <h2>
    This is demo site for
    <img alt="" src="image link here"></img>
  </h2>
</div>
```

The above one is DOM of that page title. I don't know how to use this element, please any one can help me.

Comment: You are using assertEquals wrong. It should be the other way around assertEquals(expectedTitle,actualTitle);

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse real page title (`<title>This is demo site for</title>`) that should be present in `<head>` with just a simple header string located somewhere in the `<body>` of page

Try following:

```
String actualTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@class="page-title"]/h2'))getText();
String expectedTitle = "This is demo site for";
assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to verify title in elements:

```
public String verifyTitle(String locator, String data) {    
   String txt = getElement(locator).getText();
        if (txt.equals(data)) {
            System.out.println("Title name present");
                }
```

or another way:

```
public String verifyElementTitle(String locator, String data) {
    String expectedTxt = data;
    String actualTxt = getElement(locator).getText();
    if (actualTxt.equals(expectedTxt)) {
        System.out.println("Title name present");
        return Constants.PASS;
    } else
        System.out.println("Title mismach or not present");
    return Constants.FAIL;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing linked with testing and Selenium in your answer

Comment: it one piece of code from my framework, which verifies the title of an element(Selenium hybrid framework)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying